# Application Description in Manifest file

Tags: java, manifest

I'm developing an about-box `JFrame` that contain information about application:

- Company Name
- Version
- Description

For application Version and company name i retrieve the value from the manifest file fields (company-name, version-number) of the application jar package, 
how can i do for description field ?

Is there a field in the manifest file suitable to be used for contain application description ?

Comment: why not create your own manifest `key:value` pair?

Comment: Isn't a predefined key for the application description yet ?

Comment: cant see such on http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest but you're free to create your own